# I am trying to read a file and to show the reading progress in %. I have tried following code but I am not able to divide in chunks & show progress

Tags: c

I am trying to read a file and to show the reading progress in percentage.  I have tried out the following code but I am not able to divide in chunks and show progress.  How should I show progress?

```
    printf("File contains %ld bytes!\n", fsize);

    buf = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*fsize);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        printf("Memory error!\n");
        return 2;
    }
    else {
        printf("Allocating memory!\n");

        bytes_read = fread(buf, 1, fsize, pf);

        printf("number of bytes read %1d",bytes_read);
```

Comment: There's no question asked here.

Comment: how would i show the progress of reading by diving it in chunks?

Comment: How big is the file, i.e., the value of fsize?

Comment: a file can be anything and of any size.but now suppose its 889 mb file

Comment: [?](https://www.ross.click/2011/02/creating-a-progress-bar-in-c-or-any-other-console-app/)

Comment: suppose my file name is abc.rar and its size is 50000 bytes.then while reading file once it reads 10000 byte then it should show 10 % reading done...again aftr reading 20000bytes it should shw 20 % done.. likewise....

Comment: How do you consider 100,000 out of 500,000 ought to show "10% done"? That would be similar to what Windows' Copy Time Remaining dialog shows.

Comment: It might be operating system specific. On Linux you might use [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), at least for file of a few gigabytes, to view them as range of virtual memory addresses.

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a rough draft, to illustrate replacing the one `fread()` you currently use:

```
size_t numToRead = fsize;
char* bufPtr = &buf[0];
while ( numToRead > 0 )
{
    int percentDone = 0;
    size_t numSuccessful = fread( bufPtr, 1, 10000, pf ); // choose size
    bufPtr += numSuccessful;
    numToRead -= numSuccessful;
    percentDone = ( 100 * ( fsize - numToRead ) / fsize );
    // display percentage as you like
}
```

Disclaimer:  I have not compiled this snippet, so please forgive typos.